# How to unlock files using handle.exe and process name?

Tags: windows-7, sysinternals

I tried Unlocker 1.9.1 but it doesn't work correctly for me on Windows7 (worked ok on Windows XP) and also I tried LockHunter 2.0.2.103 x64 and reported a bug but .... LockHunter actually unlocks the file from GUI but not from command line.

So I want to use handle.exe by [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) to unlock one file "TestPro.log". I know the absolut path if it helps. I can list and all processes that locked the file by executing

```
C:\Windows\system32>c:\edutester\progs\handle testpro.log
java.exe           pid: 2120   type: File           338: C:\Users\Public\TestPro
\TestPro Automation Framework\Logs\TestPro.log
java.exe           pid: 1004   type: File           934: C:\Users\Public\TestPro
\TestPro Automation Framework\Logs\TestPro.log
```

What I need to know how to unlock the file using above info from **command line automatically**. No user intervention is possible.

- Windows 7 64bit
- Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `handle.exe` once to list the PIDs and handles, then again multiple times to close each one.

Use the `for /f` command to loop through the result of the first command. I don't have a Windows machine handy to test on, but it should look something like this:

**From a batch file:**

```
for /F "tokens=3,6 delims=: " %%I IN ('handle.exe -accepteula TestPro.log') DO handle.exe -c %%J -y -p %%I
```

**From the command-line:**

```
for /F "tokens=3,6 delims=: " %I IN ('handle.exe -accepteula TestPro.log') DO handle.exe -c %J -y -p %I
```

Comment: I cannot make it work. Your code gives me `('handle.exe was unexpected at this time.` I think there is missing `in` before `('handle.exe was unexpected at this time.` But then `%%J contains `:` so it's not valid argument for handle.exe

Comment: Yeah, I remember having trouble getting the command exactly right, but I can't remember what I did off the top of my head. I'm trying to get access to my batch file again so I can update my answer with the right syntax.

Comment: @Radek I updated my answer with the actual code I used. Looks like I got `%%I` and `%%J` mixed up, and we need the colon as a delimiter. Try this and see how it goes.

Comment: Works nicely (both batch file & command line versions) if cmd started as administrator. Any idea how I can make it work as a part of my overnight automation testing? `runas` doesn't work for me in this case.

Comment: Got it working. The trick is that the command to run under runas is in fact cmd.exe and the argument for cmd is your code. I was doing it without cmd.

Comment: @StephenJennings - any chance you could whip up this same syntax in powershell?

Answer (score 1):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx

**TEST AND DISPLAY (DRY-RUN):**

```
for /f "tokens=3,6 skip=5 delims=: " %i in ('handle.exe -accepteula notepad.exe') do @echo %i %j
```

**EXECUTE (CLOSE HANDLES):**

```
for /f "tokens=3,6 skip=5 delims=: " %i in ('handle.exe -accepteula notepad.exe') do handle.exe -c %j -y -p %i
```

**EXECUTE (CLOSE HANDLES) AND THEN TASKKILL:**

```
for /f "tokens=3,6 skip=5 delims=: " %i in ('handle.exe -accepteula notepad.exe') do handle.exe -c %j -y -p %i & taskkill /t /f /PID %i
```

Comment: Can you expand on this and explain how it improves on the (four and a half year old) [accepted answer](http://superuser.com/a/486676/461558)?

Comment: I see your commands are different than the accepted answer, so its a legitimate answer.  However, as bertieb indicated, your answer *needs* an explanation as to what your commands will do and how they address the OPs question. Thanks for contributing to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

Execution from the context menu without a bat file.
1) Put the file handle64.exe in C:\Windows.
2) Create and execute reg script

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\WhatBlockFile]
    "Icon"="C:\\ico\\Buttons\\Annotate_Help.ico"
    "MUIVerb"="Что блокирует?"
    "Position"="Top"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\WhatBlockFile\command]
    @="C:\\Windows\\system32\\Cmd.exe /c C:\\Windows\\handle64.exe -u \"%1\" & pause"
```